# Calling Objective-c function in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im trying to implement CometChat in my swift application. I managed to import the Objective-c framework successfully via a bridging header. But now I'm stuck trying to call Objective-C methods from swift.

This is the method from the interface i want to call:

```
- (void)loginWithURL:(NSString *)siteURL
            username:(NSString *)username
            password:(NSString *)password
             success:(void(^)(NSDictionary *response))success
             failure:(void(^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

And this is how the method is called from Objective-C:

```
 [cometChat loginWithURL:@"localhost/cometchat/" username:usernameTextField.text password:passwordTextField.text success:^(NSDictionary *response) {

                    NSLog(@"SDK log : Username/Password Login Success %@",response);

                    [self handleLogin];

                } failure:^(NSError *error) {

                    NSLog(@"SDK log : Username/Password Login Error%@",error);

                    [self handleLoginError:@[@0,error]];

                }];
```

So far i have this:

```
 cometChat.loginWithURL("localhost/cometchat/", username: EmailField.text, password: PasswordField.text){
            (success: [NSDictionary], failure:NSError) in {

            println("did i make it here?")

            }

    }
```

The problem is, it says that there is missing argument "success", but its a mystery to me how it can be an argument, when it clearly returns the response. I want to know how to put together this method call. I also used the **objectivec2swift** converter, but it wasn't any help. Also, i have no clue what the @ means before the **@[@0,error]**

I know its a beginners question, but i already wasted a whole day on this, since i couldn't find any tutorials on how to call such "complex" Obj-C methods from swift.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :-

```
cometChat.loginWithURL("localhost/cometchat/", username: "abc", password: "123", success: { (response) -> Void in

        print("SDK log : Username/Password Login Success \(response)")


        }) { ( error) -> Void in

            print("SDK log : Username/Password Login Error \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the Objective-C signature, you see that the method takes two closures: `success` is a void function that takes a dictionary, and `failure` is a void function that takes an error.

In your Swift code you have only one closure: a void function that takes a dictionary and an error.

You either need to change the Objective-C method to take just one closure, or change the Swift code to provide two closures.

Comment: so something like (dont have access to the mac to test right now): cometChat.loginWithURL("localhost/cometchat/", username: EmailField.text, password: PasswordField.text){
            (success: [NSDictionary]) in {
            println("did i make it here?")

            }, (failure:NSError) in{}

    }

Comment: Syntax is object.method (value1, param2: value2, param3: value3, param4: value4, param5: value5). That's not what you are writing. Read the Swift book. It seems you haven't learned the language but are just copying examples; that doesn't work. Again, read and understand the book.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, and the last parameter is a block / closure, then you can write the last parameter after the function call in { }. That applies to the *last* block only.

Anyway, you are trying to pass a closure with two parameters success and failure. You need to pass *two* closures, one as the success parameter of your function, with a parameter response, and one either as the failure parameter of your function, or following the function, with a parameter error.